# ElementTree works with .iter() but not with .find()

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am new with ElementTree. I want to get some values (text) of a xml file. When I try root.iter() the output is a lot of tags. But when I try root.find('someTag') or root.findall('someTag') the out put is None. I can not understand this. Can you help me?
See a bit of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"       href="/3.2/style/exchange.xsl"?>
<ops:world-patent-data xmlns="http://www.epo.org/exchange" xmlns:ops="http://ops.epo.org" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<exchange-documents>
    <exchange-document system="ops.epo.org" family-id="19768124" country="EP" doc-number="1000000" kind="A1">
        <bibliographic-data>
            <publication-reference>
                <document-id document-id-type="docdb">
                    <country>EP</country>
                    <doc-number>1000000</doc-number>
                    <kind>A1</kind>
                    <date>20000517</date>
```

If .iter() show tags, why I cant find this tags with .find()?

```
tree = ET.parse('topnewsfeed.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for x in root.iter():
    print(x.tag)
```

the out put is:

```
{http://ops.epo.org}world-patent-data
{http://www.epo.org/exchange}exchange-documents
{http://www.epo.org/exchange}exchange-document
{http://www.epo.org/exchange}bibliographic-data
{http://www.epo.org/exchange}publication-reference
(...)
```

If I try:

```
for x in root.find('{http://www.epo.org/exchange}exchange-document'):
    print(x.tag)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `root.find('{http://www.epo.org/exchange}exchange-document')` tries to locate the first `{http://www.epo.org/exchange}exchange-document` child of `root`. There probably is no such element. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I past a part of xml code.

Comment: `exchange-document` is not a child of `root`; it is a grandchild. And `find()` can only find one element.

Answer (score 1):

A short and quick variant of correction is:

- Replace *find* with *findall*.
- As *exchange-document* is not a direct descendant of the root, prepend
  the XPath with *.//*, to look at any depth.

So change your code to:

```
for x in root.findall('.//{http://www.epo.org/exchange}exchange-document'):
   print(x.tag)
```

But placement of full namespaces in each XPath is not a good idea.
Instead I recommend to:

- Define a dictionary with all shortcuts and namespaces used in your XPaths.
- In each XPath specify the namespace with the respecive shortcut (+ a colon
  as a separator), but this time without surrounding braces.
- Pass this dictionary as the second parameter in *findall*.

So the second, (IMHO a more readable) variant is:

```
ns = {'exch': 'http://www.epo.org/exchange'}
for x in root.findall('.//exch:exchange-document', ns):
    print(x.tag)
```